# How to turn on debug and trace logging for weblogic?

Tags: java, weblogic

I understand there are very many ways to do this- just not very clear to me which ones I should use. Some of the answers on google dont work and the docs on the site are murky to me.
thanks

Comment: What are you trying to debug or trace in WLS? Is it the application server itself, or your own code?

Answer (score 1):

the quickest way is to specify a JVM System property of the type -Dweblogic.debug.YOURSUBSYSTEM  and also -Dweblogic.log.StdoutSeverity="Debug"

or in alternative set it from the WebLogic console in the server/debug/weblogic/YOURSUBSYSTEM  and remember to set the log severity level to Debug, for the server you are troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

This differs on the version of WebLogic you are using. For >= 9.2, click on the Server and go to the Debug tab.

Here you can expand the trees and enable very detailed and specific logging. Hope that helps.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/task_runtimes/DefineDebugSettings.html